# Google Analytics Android trackEvent arguments error

Tags: android, eclipse, google-analytics, arguments

When trying to implement the method:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("AdultAbxActivity Clicks", 
"Comments Click", infection, 0);
```

I get this error from Eclipse:

*The method trackEvent(String, String, String, Long) in the type Tracker is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, int)*

It suggests I cast argument '0' to 'long'.

Yet the official reference states that the last argument should be an int:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking?hl=en

Should I cast this as a long as eclipse suggests, and will it work. Or is my Eclipse wrong?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in your post is pointing to web tracking section. I suppose that you are using Google Analytics Android SDK. So for [trackEvent](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events) method the arguments should be (String, String , String, Long). If it is so then just change the line to the following:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("AdultAbxActivity Clicks", 
        "Comments Click", infection, 0l);
```